# calculating map from $\pi_4(SL2)$ to $\pi_4(C6)$

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory

Given a nilpotent element $X \in C_6 = \mathfrak{sp}(12)$ we know by Jacobson-Morozov/Malcev that this can be extended to an $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ triple $\{H,X,Y\} \in C_6$, this is the same as a homomorphism $\phi: \mathfrak{sl}(2) \rightarrow \mathfrak{sp}(12)$. Now, this induces a map $\Phi: \text{SL}(2) \rightarrow \text{Sp}(12)$ which furthermore induces a map $\Phi ^* : \pi_4(\text{SL}(2)) = \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 = \pi_4(\text{Sp}(12))$.

Firstly, does this map depend on the nilpotent element chosen? and if so how does one determine whether this map is $0$ or $1$?

The answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259487/computation-of-pi-4-of-simple-lie-groups by Matthias suggests one can look at the root systems, however I am unsure how to make use of this.

Also I am looking to do a similar study of the maps:

$$ \mathbb{Z}_2 =\pi_5(SL2) \rightarrow \pi_5(Sp(12)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$$
$$ \mathbb{Z}_2 = \pi_8(SL2) \rightarrow \pi_8(SO(13)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$$
$$ \mathbb{Z}_2 \times\mathbb{Z}_2 = \pi_{12}(SL2) \rightarrow \pi_{12}(Sp(12)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$$

however I am not even sure how to begin tackling this, are there any obvious papers I should have a look at?